# Superstring mass between 2 D-branes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, string-theory, mass, branes

The mass of a superstring between 2 parallel D-branes of dimension $p$ and $q$ is
$$m^2=(N−a)+(y/2π)^2$$
But what is the value of the normal ordering constant $a$?